# Running Selenium with Chrome driver and disable chrome browser view

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm using the following driver :

```
WebDriver m_driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait waitableDriver =  new WebDriverWait(m_driver , 10);
```

The first action is:

```
waitableDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='"+selectionID+"']"))).click();
```

this is will sellect an id on the page, and then i'm starting to grab the information. the problem is that while using

```
WebDriver m_driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

everything works just fine. while trying to change it to :

```
m_driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

the above click action is not working, is there any way to fix it / using chrome driver and disable the view of the browser ?

Comment: click action was just ignored or you have an exception which could really help to solve the issue?

Comment: please provide exception, it'll help a lot with solving the issue